# Cuando "te toca jugar", ¿a qué acepción de "tocar" nos referimos?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, definiciones

Cuando jugamos una partida a algo que se juega por turnos, cuando te llega dicho turno decimos que "me toca jugar" o simplemente "me toca". Revisando las acepciones de *[tocar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Zw9dWu5)* no he visto ninguna que encaje con dicho significado. Podría ser la 24:

> Dicho de una cosa: Caer en suerte.

Sin embargo entiendo que eso es para frases como "me ha tocado la lotería", donde interviene el azar más que los turnos. Nuestro compañero aparente dijo en [una respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20298/12637) que la acepción a la que se refería era la 23:

> Dicho de una parte o porción de algo que se reparte entre varios o les es común: Caber o pertenecer

Pero tampoco me encaja porque eso es para frases del estilo "tocamos a 7 euros por cabeza", usada cuando hay algo que repartir.

Luego no termino de ver qué acepción de *tocar* se usa en el caso de los turnos. ¿Falta alguna acepción en el diccionario? ¿O estoy malinterpretando las definiciones?

Answer (score 8):

En el DLE tenemos [esta acepción para **tocar**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Zw9dWu5#KLpxX6m):

> 21. intr. Ser de la obligación o cargo de alguien.

Si he interpretado bien esta definición, posibles ejemplos serían:

> Me toca guardia esta noche.
>   Te toca hacer caja cuando cerremos.
>   Le toca a Juan lavar los cacharros

No veo mucha diferencia entre las frases anteriores y algo como *"Te toca tirar"*, así que creo que sería esta la acepción que usamos en realidad.

---

Sobre si cuadra más esta definición o la apuntada por Charlie en [su respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/30921/) (*"19. intr. Pertenecer por algún derecho o título."*), podríamos entrar en el debate de si tirar cuando te toca es un derecho o una obligación... En juegos en los que puedas [pasar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=S33P1kX#M1598eK) o ceder tu turno, podría interpretarse como un derecho, mientras que en el resto de juegos sería una obligación puesto que, si no tiras cuando te toca, el juego no puede continuar (al menos, no contigo en él).

Answer (score 4):

El DRAE puede tener sus lapsus. En el [Free Dictionary](https://es.thefreedictionary.com/tocar), encontramos la acepción en cuestión en la entrada (19):

> 19. Llegar el turno de una cosa a una persona *ahora te toca hablar a ti*. corresponder

Answer (score 2):

En el *Diccionario esencial* de la RAE se aclara el dilema. La acepción 14 de *tocar* dice:

> Corresponder por algún derecho o título. *Te toca intervenir.*

Repasando las acepciones del DLE veo que existe la acepción, solo que su redacción queda algo más confusa dado que además carece de ejemplo:

> 19. intr. Pertenecer por algún derecho o título.

Comment: Es interesante que la palabra tocar viene etimologicamente de la onomatopeya del sonido de "toc". en que momento Habra pasado a ser la indicacion de una posecion ?

Answer (score 0):

"Cuando jugamos una partida a algo que se juega por turnos, **cuando te llega dicho turno decimos** que "me toca jugar" o simplemente "me toca" ".

---

Al leer "**cuando te llega dicho turno decimos...me toca jugar**" me hizo pensar que quizás esa acepción "que no encaja", habría que buscarla en otro lugar, aunque realmente eso no era lo más lógico, es decir, lo que me llamo la atención fue al leer; "cuando **llega el turno es cuando te toca**".

Así busque en el verbo llegar, donde se puede leer lo siguiente;

> 3. intr. Dicho de una cosa o de una acción: **Venir por su orden o tocar por su turno a alguien**.

Por tanto esta acepción, paradójicamente, no habría que buscarla en "tocar", sino en el verbo "llegar", pues también es posible que uno espere que "**llegue**" algo, en este caso el turno.

Cuando te **llega** tu turno es cuando te toca. Este "encaje" de "**tocar por su turno**", es lo que expresa este apartado tercero del V. "Llegar".

https://dle.rae.es/llegar

Answer (score 0):

También esta la acepción que habla de su uso coloquial como equivalente de **corresponder** dónde, a su vez, define el verbo **tocar** como sinónimo sin aclarar la acepción. Esto que resulta en un ciclo indefinido porque resulta que ninguna de las otras acepciones de **corresponder** se ajusta a el significado que estamos discutiendo.

> **tocar**le a alguien bailar con la más fea
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Corresponderle resolver un asunto muy difícil o desagradable.

Opino que en una de esas ocasiones en las que se aplica la frase "El mapa no es el terreno". Todas las acepciones que se han propuesto, se aproximan auque no **tocan** el significado preciso.